# Dependency problem installing dell osam on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, 15.10, dependencies

I have a simple problem with dependencies.

I want to install a Server management package from Dell called OSAM
on Ubuntu 15.10. For the installation I added an old repo provided by the dell community. [The guide I used](https://oitibs.com/dell-openmanage-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

If I want to install the srvadmin-all meta pkg, I have unmet dependencies. Following the chain of unmet dependencies, I found out that a package has been replaced.

```
sudo apt-get install srvadmin-omcommon
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
srvadmin-omcommon : Depends: libsmbios2 but it is not installable

sudo apt-get install libsmbios2
However the following packages replace it:
libsmbios2v5:i386 libsmbios2v5
```

How can announce that libsmbios2v5 replaced the libsmbios2?

Do I just have to link the libsmbios2 to libsmbios2v5 or is there any other way how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dell has to update their software to work correctly with the newer library. However, you can manually install libsmbios2 from the 14.04 repositories and hope for the best: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libsmbios2

Installing software from older distributions may also cause dependency errors, but this particular package didn't send me any warnings when I tried installing it on my computer running 15.10. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no support for Ubuntu by Dell and the repo maintained by the community

Answer (score 1):

I had to install three older libs from trusty to get this to work on wily:

```
libsmbios (2_2.2.28-2)
python-libsmbios(2.2.28-2)
smbios-utils (2.2.28-2)
```

then:

```
apt-mark hold smbios-utils
apt-mark hold libsmbios2
apt-mark hold python-libsmbios
```

And finally:

```
apt-get install srvadmin-all
```